# Keep previous page in Vue alive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps

I am currently trying to [build a small PWA](https://bowvie-test.firebaseapp.com) to mimic an Android app and have come across Vuejs.

But currently I have ran into an issue that I have not been able to fix. When you scroll one of the lists on one of the homepages ([movies](https://bowvie-test.firebaseapp.com/movies)/[tvshows](https://bowvie-test.firebaseapp.com/tvshows)/[news](https://bowvie-test.firebaseapp.com/news)) and click on an item I would like to retain the position of those lists so when the user navigates back they wouldn't have to scroll again to get to the same item.

I tried a few things with the `keep-alive` property but fail to understand how it works. My app page currently looks like this. I use the `:key="$route.fullPath"` to make a detail page reload when you go from movie to movie.

```
<div id="content">
  <keep-alive>
    <transition :name="transitionName" mode="out-in">
      <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    </transition>
  </keep-alive>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <div class="bottom-bar">
    <md-bottom-bar md-type="shift" md-sync-route>
      <md-bottom-bar-item id="bottom-bar-item-movies" md-label="Movies" to="/movies"
                          md-icon="movie"></md-bottom-bar-item>
      <md-bottom-bar-item id="bottom-bar-item-tvshows" md-label="TV Shows" to="/tvshows"
                          md-icon="tv"></md-bottom-bar-item>
      <md-bottom-bar-item id="bottom-bar-item-watchlist" md-label="News" to="/news"
                          md-icon="language"></md-bottom-bar-item>
    </md-bottom-bar>
  </div>
</div>
```

A detail page has a route with the name of the type and its id like `/movies/348350`. On a detail page there is a button to navigate back by using `this.$router.go(-1)`.

Is there an easy way that I have missed till now how to do this?

Comment: keep-alive keeps component alive, not a page. Maybe you should use vuex to keep you data alive and timetravel back when needed

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. However, it is 2023 now, and if I put `router-view` inside `keep-alive`, vue-router throws me a warning that `router-view` can no longer be used inside `keep-alive`. I hope someone could update this answer. I am using vue-router@4.2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view), `<keep-alive>` needs to be inside:

```vue
<transition :name="transitionName" mode="out-in">
  <keep-alive>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
</transition>
```